# PHP jQuery Post - returns too much HTML

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem when using jQuery Post, the PHP returns all the HTML of the page up to the newly created HTML, rather then just the HTML that is output by the PHP.

As an example say the php outputs: `'<div>Some Content</div>'`

Then the jQuery Post returns: `'<html><head>...all the head content...</head><body>...other content...<div>Some Content</div>'`

Here's the jQuery (link to full code: http://pastebin.com/U7R8PqX1):

```
        jQuery("form[ID^=product_form]").submit(function() {

        var current_url = js_data.current_url;
        form_values = jQuery(this).serialize();

        jQuery.post(current_url+"?ajax=true", form_values, function(returned_data) {

                jQuery('div.shopping-cart').html(returned_data);

            }

        });

        return false;

    });
```

And here's the PHP (version 5.3.6 - link to full code: http://pastebin.com/zjSUUbmL):

```
        function output_cart() 
    {


        ob_start();
        echo $this->output_cart_html();
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        echo $output;  

        exit();

    }

        function output_cart_html() {


            if (!isset($_SESSION['cart_items'])) 
            {
                $output = '<div class="cart_content faded">BASKET - Empty</div>';
                return $output;

            } else {

                $total_items = 0;
                $total_items = 0;
                $items_in_cart = $_SESSION['cart_items'];

                // work out total price and total items
                foreach ($items_in_cart as $item_in_cart) {
                    $total_items += $item_in_cart['quantity'];
                    $total_price += floatval($item_in_cart['updated_price']*$item_in_cart['quantity']);
                }

                $template_url = get_bloginfo('template_directory');
                $output = '';
                $output_price = $dp_shopping_cart_settings['dp_currency_symbol'].number_format($total_price,2);
                if($total_items == 1){ $item_text = ' Item'; } else { $item_text = ' Items'; }
                $output .= $total_items . $item_text;
                $output .= '&nbsp;<span class="bullet"></span>&nbsp; Total '.$output_price;
                // empty cart btn
                $output .= '<form action="" method="post" class="empty_cart">
                    <input type="hidden" name="ajax_action" value="empty_cart" />
                    <span class="emptycart"> <a href="'.htmlentities(add_query_arg("ajax_action", "empty_cart", remove_query_arg("ajax")), ENT_QUOTES).'"><img src="'.$template_url.'/images/empty.png" width="9" height="9" title="Empty Your Items" alt="Empty Your Items" />Empty Your Cart</a></span>
                    </form>';
                // check out btn
                $output .= '&nbsp;<span class="bullet"></span>&nbsp; <span class="gocheckout">'.$this->output_checkout_link().' </span>';

                return $output;

            }

    }
```

Comment: The output buffering you're using there is completely redundant. Also, I only see two (supposed) class methods. Where's the rest of the PHP code?

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for having a look, here's the full Jquery: http://pastebin.com/U7R8PqX1 and full PHP: http://pastebin.com/zjSUUbmL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it turns out my problem was with the way Wordpress processes AJAX requests. The plugin I was building on top of was using AJAX but didn't have these issues (I'm not sure why maybe because they were using eval), so I hadn't realised there was a correct way of using AJAX with Wordpress. Here's a bunch of information if anyone else has similar problems:

---

http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

http://byronyasgur.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/frontend-forward-facing-ajax-in-wordpress/
(this one really helped me out, a very simple example that I was able to adapt)

-- sorry I couldn't post more links because I'm too new on this site, but check out the links at the bottom of the first link above, especially the '5 Tips'.

---

As I'm using classes I instantiated the class from the index file of my plugin with this:

```
    if ($_POST['action'] === 'action_name') {

        $class_obj = new \namespace_name\class();
        add_action('wp_ajax_action_name', array($class_obj, 'method_name'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_action_name', array($class_obj, 'method_name'));

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if the form has been posted yet with the PHP. To do this, just check if the 'ajax' parameter is there, or send another $_GET variable if you wish (by adding `&anotherparementer=1` to the end of the jQuery post URL). Example:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
//your PHP code here that submits the form, i.e. the functions that you have, etc.
}
else { 
?>
<html>
<head>
head content here...
</head>
<body>
body content here...
</body>
</html>
<?php
} 
?>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I do check that everything is posted, and then call the methods I posted above.

Comment: @peter.shep What do you have in the `else`? Because this is exactly what I do, and it only returns to jQuery what I echo out, so I don't really see why it's sending the rest of the HTML with it. Could you maybe post the rest of the PHP in [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/) or something? That way I can see what is going on.

Comment: Ok here's the full Jquery: http://pastebin.com/U7R8PqX1 and full PHP: http://pastebin.com/zjSUUbmL